# Is there anyway to send a text message from Twilio so that the from number contains an extension?

Tags: php, twilio

Is there anyway to send a text message from Twilio so that the from number contains an extension?

Something like this:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "...";
$token = "...";
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$client->account->messages->sendMessage(
    "+441337944066+123#", // From
    "+441234567891", // To
    "Hello world" // Body
);
```

At the moment attempting this produces this error message:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The 'From' number +441337944066+123# is not a valid phone number or shortcode.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Support here.

Unfortunately we do not support extensions when sending messages.

However if you're looking to dial an extension on voice calls you can use the SendDigits parameter:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

Tom

Answer (score 1):

It was my understanding that you needed to send messages with a `FROM` value being a valid Twillio number. Since the wrapper/helper is using the REST API it should still be bound by those restrictions. See documentation about that here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

So, unless you purchased the number from Twillio and it has an extension, unfortunately, I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the docs, thanks. And it does say "A Twilio phone number enabled for the type of message you wish to send. Only phone numbers or short codes purchased from Twilio work here; you cannot (for example) spoof messages from your own cell phone number.". But my intention isn't to spoof any messages or anything. If a caller was to phone the number that they received that text from, I want it to automatically add the extension to the call. Are you aware of any workaround?

Comment: I think I understand and what you're looking to do is format the telephone number in such a way WITHIN the message that the extension is included. That's something you do in your message and not by modifying the `FROM` number, which isn't something you can do in this case.